# Best Way to create a back and front office application with symfony 4

Tags: routes, symfony4

I'm creating a new application with a front and a back-office, my bak office give the possibility to create society, and those society, created in back, should give the possibility to be recognised in the url in front, i don't know how to do so,..

i've tried to modified my security.yml like so =>

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/\w+/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

and i'm currently trying to recognize the society in the url of the front, like this ( in my  config/routes.yaml ) =>

```
salarie_index:
    path: /{_clientname}/*
```

And it works fine, BUT, when i'm trying to access my bak office, it's now  considered as a society >__<"

I expect to be able to specify to my routing that if the clientname is "admin", then it should not map to this route,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

I can't do this because my backoffice is not company dependant, wich mean i don't need company at all in the url, wich is on the contrary needed in the url of the front,...

In fact i think i can use the configuration there for the purpose =>

routes.yml =>

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

admin:
    resource: "../../src/Controller/Admin/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: '/admin'

salarie:
    resource: "../../src/Controller/Salarie/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: '/{_clientname}'
    requirements:
        _clientname: '^((\w+))+'
        #_clientname: '^(((?!admin).)(\w+))+'
```

And this security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Salarie:
            algorithm: auto


    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_salarie_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Salarie
                property: email
        app_admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\AdminUser
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|ico|js)/
            security: false
        admin_area:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: app_admin_provider
            form_login:
                provider: app_admin_provider
                login_path: login_admin
                username_parameter: sign_in[email]
                password_parameter: sign_in[password]
                check_path: login_check_admin
            logout:
                path: /logout_admin
                target: /admin
        salarie:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/\w+
            form_login:
                provider: app_salarie_provider
                login_path: login_salarie
                username_parameter: sign_in[email]
                password_parameter: sign_in[password]
                check_path: login_check_salarie
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/\w+/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

With those files it looks like i've got the result i was looking for !

Any way thanks for your answer, have a nice day o/

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, it does seem you are overcomplicating it. What is keeping you from having different routes ?

You could just have a route for your admin : `/admin`

And another route for your companies (society) : `/company/{_clientname}`